# The Angular AoT build failed when running the release command in Ionic 3

Tags: android, angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to run the app on my Sony Z2 smart phone. I use the following command:

```
ionic build android --prod --release
```

I get a error in my console like this:

> typescript error
>               Type CirckelmovementPage in C:/Users/fearcoder/Documents/natuurkundeformules/src/pages/circkelmovement/circkelmovement.ts
>             is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in
>   C:/Users/fearcoder/Documents/natuurkundeformules/src/app/app.module.ts
>   and CirckelmovementPageModule in C:/Users/fearcoder
>               /Documents/natuurkundeformules/src/pages/circkelmovement/circkelmovement.module.ts!
>
> ```
>       Please consider moving CirckelmovementPage in
> ```
>
> C:/Users/fearcoder/Documents/natuurkundeformules/src/pages/circkelmovement/circkelmovement.ts
>             to a higher module that imports AppModule in
>   C:/Users/fearcoder/Documents/natuurkundeformules/src/app/app.module.ts
>             and CirckelmovementPageModule in
>   C:/Users/fearcoder/Documents/natuurkundeformules/src/pages/circkelmovement/circkelmovement.module.ts.
>
> ```
>       You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes
> ```
>
> CirckelmovementPage in
>   C:/Users/fearcoder/Documents/natuurkundeformules/src/pages/circkelmovement/circkelmovement.ts
>   then import that NgModule
>               in AppModule in C:/Users/fearcoder/Documents/natuurkundeformules/src/app/app.module.ts
>
> ```
>       and CirckelmovementPageModule in
> ```
>
> C:/Users/fearcoder/Documents/natuurkundeformules/src/pages/circkelmovement/circkelmovement.module.ts.

These are the files

**circkelmovement.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AdMobFree, AdMobFreeBannerConfig } from '@ionic-native/admob-free';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-circkelmovement',
  templateUrl: 'circkelmovement.html',
})
export class CirckelmovementPage {

  ray:any;
  circulationtime:any;
  result:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private admob: AdMobFree) {
  } 

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
      isTesting: true,
      autoShow: true
    };
    this.admob.banner.config(bannerConfig);

    this.admob.banner.prepare()
      .then(() => {
        this.admob.banner.show()
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }

  calculateWebSpeed(ray, circulationtime){      
    return this.result = "Baansnelheid: " + (2 * Math.PI * ray / circulationtime) + " m/s";    
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { AdMobFree } from '@ionic-native/admob-free';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { SpeedPage } from '../pages/speed/speed';
import { DistancePage } from '../pages/distance/distance';
import { TimePage } from '../pages/time/time';
import { WorkPage } from '../pages/work/work';
import { KinenergyPage } from '../pages/kinenergy/kinenergy';
import { GravityenergyPage } from '../pages/gravityenergy/gravityenergy';
import { GravityforcePage } from '../pages/gravityforce/gravityforce';
import { CirckelmovementPage } from '../pages/circkelmovement/circkelmovement';
import { ElectricityenergyPage } from '../pages/electricityenergy/electricityenergy';
import { LawohmPage } from '../pages/lawohm/lawohm';
import { LenslawPage } from '../pages/lenslaw/lenslaw';
import { LorentzforcewirePage } from '../pages/lorentzforcewire/lorentzforcewire';
import { DensityPage } from '../pages/density/density';
import { PressurePage } from '../pages/pressure/pressure';
import { LensstrenghtPage } from '../pages/lensstrenght/lensstrenght';
import { PowerPage } from '../pages/power/power';
import { CurrentstrenghtPage } from '../pages/currentstrenght/currentstrenght';
import { FrequencyPage } from '../pages/frequency/frequency';
import { WavespeedPage } from '../pages/wavespeed/wavespeed';
import { MassPage } from '../pages/mass/mass';
import { LorentzparticlePage } from '../pages/lorentzparticle/lorentzparticle';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    SpeedPage,
    DistancePage,
    TimePage,
    WorkPage,
    KinenergyPage,
    GravityenergyPage,
    GravityforcePage,
    CirckelmovementPage,
    ElectricityenergyPage,
    LawohmPage,
    LenslawPage,
    LorentzforcewirePage,
    DensityPage,
    PressurePage,
    LensstrenghtPage,
    PowerPage,
    CurrentstrenghtPage,
    FrequencyPage,
    WavespeedPage,
    MassPage,  
    LorentzparticlePage       
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    SpeedPage,
    DistancePage,
    TimePage,
    WorkPage,
    KinenergyPage,
    GravityenergyPage,
    GravityforcePage,
    CirckelmovementPage,
    ElectricityenergyPage,
    LawohmPage,
    LenslawPage,
    LorentzforcewirePage,
    DensityPage,
    PressurePage,
    LensstrenghtPage,
    PowerPage,
    CurrentstrenghtPage,
    FrequencyPage,
    WavespeedPage,
    MassPage,   
    LorentzparticlePage    
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    AdMobFree,
    InAppBrowser,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**circkelmovement.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CirckelmovementPage } from './circkelmovement';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CirckelmovementPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(CirckelmovementPage),
  ],
})
export class CirckelmovementPageModule {}
```

I have read that this command with solve the performance issues when loading the app. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Kind regards

Comment: So since you are using lazy loading you don't need to import your CirckelmovementPage in app.module.ts. Did you try removing it? Also remove it from all the declarations etc etc in app.module.ts. I would suggest you read a guide on how you do lazy loading pages / components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you use lazy loaded pages you don't need to import or declare those in this app.module.ts at all as they will be part of their own module in their folder. So for all lazy loaded pages do have:

- lazy loaded page own named module file in the page's (you seems to have it for this particular page)
- in your app logic when you load such a page (using navCtrl for example) you need to use the name of the page as string not as Component

So in your code uncomment those pages that you lazy load:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { AdMobFree } from '@ionic-native/admob-free';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { SpeedPage } from '../pages/speed/speed';
import { DistancePage } from '../pages/distance/distance';
import { TimePage } from '../pages/time/time';
import { WorkPage } from '../pages/work/work';
import { KinenergyPage } from '../pages/kinenergy/kinenergy';
import { GravityenergyPage } from '../pages/gravityenergy/gravityenergy';
import { GravityforcePage } from '../pages/gravityforce/gravityforce';
// import { CirckelmovementPage } from '../pages/circkelmovement/circkelmovement';
import { ElectricityenergyPage } from '../pages/electricityenergy/electricityenergy';
import { LawohmPage } from '../pages/lawohm/lawohm';
import { LenslawPage } from '../pages/lenslaw/lenslaw';
import { LorentzforcewirePage } from '../pages/lorentzforcewire/lorentzforcewire';
import { DensityPage } from '../pages/density/density';
import { PressurePage } from '../pages/pressure/pressure';
import { LensstrenghtPage } from '../pages/lensstrenght/lensstrenght';
import { PowerPage } from '../pages/power/power';
import { CurrentstrenghtPage } from '../pages/currentstrenght/currentstrenght';
import { FrequencyPage } from '../pages/frequency/frequency';
import { WavespeedPage } from '../pages/wavespeed/wavespeed';
import { MassPage } from '../pages/mass/mass';
import { LorentzparticlePage } from '../pages/lorentzparticle/lorentzparticle';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    SpeedPage,
    DistancePage,
    TimePage,
    WorkPage,
    KinenergyPage,
    GravityenergyPage,
    GravityforcePage,
    // CirckelmovementPage,
    ElectricityenergyPage,
    LawohmPage,
    LenslawPage,
    LorentzforcewirePage,
    DensityPage,
    PressurePage,
    LensstrenghtPage,
    PowerPage,
    CurrentstrenghtPage,
    FrequencyPage,
    WavespeedPage,
    MassPage,  
    LorentzparticlePage       
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    SpeedPage,
    DistancePage,
    TimePage,
    WorkPage,
    KinenergyPage,
    GravityenergyPage,
    GravityforcePage,
    // CirckelmovementPage,
    ElectricityenergyPage,
    LawohmPage,
    LenslawPage,
    LorentzforcewirePage,
    DensityPage,
    PressurePage,
    LensstrenghtPage,
    PowerPage,
    CurrentstrenghtPage,
    FrequencyPage,
    WavespeedPage,
    MassPage,   
    LorentzparticlePage    
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    AdMobFree,
    InAppBrowser,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

One more thing: make sure you are very careful with  naming conventions with your app. I see that here:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-circkelmovement',
  templateUrl: 'circkelmovement.html',
})
```

You have different selector and template url file naming. This can bite you;)
Use this as guidance: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide or follow examples of how Ionic proposes to do it but ideally have consistency in your file naming, for example:

- publish.page.html
- publish.page.module.ts
- publish.page.scss
- publish.page.ts

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation sir! I learned a lot :D